# Counting number of documents that have particular word

Tags: python

Is there any chance of optimizing this:

```
import itertools
data = [['apple', 'banana', 'banana'],['apple', 'strawberry'], ['banana', 'lemon']]
Text = itertools.chain(*data) 
for i in list(set(Text)):
    print i, sum([1 for j in data if i in j])
```

Output:

```
strawberry 1
lemon 1
apple 2
banana 2
```

Comment: This is something that can be trivially parallelized with mapreduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for d in data: 
    c.update(set(d))

c
>>>> Counter({'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'lemon': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count documents per word:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [['apple', 'banana', 'banana'], ['apple', 'strawberry'], ['banana', 'lemon']]
counts = Counter()

for document in data:
    # count unique words only; one count per document
    counts.update(set(document))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [['apple', 'banana', 'banana'], ['apple', 'strawberry'], ['banana', 'lemon']]
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for document in data:
...     # count unique words only; one count per document
...     counts.update(set(document))
... 
>>> for word, documentcount in counts.most_common():
...     print word, documentcount
... 
apple 2
banana 2
strawberry 1
lemon 1
```

Comment: Not counting words, counting documents that have that word.

Answer (score 1):

Using Counter and itertools you can write it with a single line of code:

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

Counter(itertools.chain(*map(set, data)))
```

Result:

```
Counter({'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'lemon': 1})
```

Comment: can you add some further explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Using elementary functions (set and dict):

```
res = {}
for lst in data:
    for word in set(lst):
        if word not in res:
            res[word] = 0
        res[word] += 1
print res
```

which runs `O(n log(n))` instead of `O(n^2)` like your code.